# file_put_contents(...): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I want to move my website to the internet, but when I open any page, I get an error:

> "file_put_contents(D:\htdocs\hack\storage\framework/sessions/qIbfOPu18UZp84iznUbuBeogind3RymGAdXPXdST): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

I tried to change permissions of some folders, generate a new key, clear cache, remove files in bootstrap/cache, but these ways did not help :(

Any ideas?

Thank you :)

**Here is the working solution to upload laravel project on 000webhost hosting**

https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/deploy-laravel-project-into-000webhost-site/127323

Answer (score 3):

What permission are you put in the bootstrap and storage folder? Try put 755 permission in this folders and change group for you user:www-data

Comment: First I had 755, then i changed it to 777 but it doesn't help

Comment: And group? What's group this folders?

Comment: I don't know. I use free hosting 000webhost and i'm not able to check it, but i think it's not cause of this problem

Comment: Did you check if exists this folder 'storage\framework/sessions' in your server?

Comment: Yes, i had to delete all files from this folder except .git and now everythink is ok

Answer (score 3):

> `php artisan config:cache` Run this command to fix your cache configuration.

**This one exactly working for myself** because in my case I haven't access to cPanel through SSH, so the bellow fixed my problem.

> You can delete the `bootstrap/cache/config.php` file.

Comment: It seems that delete bootstrap/cache/config.php file solve issue in my case

Answer (score 3):

There can be various reasons why that error happened.

1. Try to delete all cached files.

   `rm -rf bootstrap/cache/config.php`
   `php artisan config:clear`
   `php artisan cache:clear`
   `php artisan config:cache`
2. If the above actions does not work, then try this again.
   Give permission to the directories in storage directory:
   app, framework, logs

   `sudo chmod -R 777 storage/app`
   `sudo chmod -R 777 storage/framework`
   `sudo chmod -R 777 storage/logs`